# Inserting map overlays on circle path according to some point in the middle

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

Let's say I have a point like lat:41.01522 and lon:28.95221. I need to calculate X latx and lonx so that these points create a circle (evenly distrubuted) around this point with a given radius.

any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'm doing it:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapview, shadow);

        if(location != null){
            //---translate the GeoPoint with center to screen pixels---
            screenPts = new Point();
            mapview.getProjection().toPixels(new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6),(int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6)) , screenPts);


            //Draw accuracy marker
            GeoPoint g0 = mapview.getProjection().fromPixels(0, screenPts.y);
            GeoPoint g1 = mapview.getProjection().fromPixels(width, screenPts.y);
            l0.setLatitude(g0.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
            l0.setLongitude(g0.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
            l1.setLatitude(g1.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
            l1.setLongitude(g1.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
            float d01=l0.distanceTo(l1);
            int size=(int)(location.getAccuracy() * width / d01);
            canvas.drawCircle(screenPts.x, screenPts.y, size, paintAccuracyFill);
            canvas.drawCircle(screenPts.x, screenPts.y, size, paintAccuracyStroke);
        }
}
```

Good luck,
Luis

Comment: this is drawing a circle not inserting overlays but thank you I can make a good use of this.

Comment: @user1290141 I missinterpreter your question. The approach you are using below is the correct one. You could simplify a litle your code by using a for cycle in radians and avoiding the conversions: for(double i = 0; i < 2 * Math.PI; i += 2 * Math.PI / n). Regards

Answer (score 0):

Well, after few hours, I think I am closed enough:

```
            double lat3, lon3;
            int n = 15;
            double radius = 0.0006;
            for (double i = 0; i < 360; i += 360 / n) {

                double cos1 = radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i));
                double sin1 = radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i));
                lat3 = lat + (sin1);
                lon3 = lon + (cos1);
                Log.i("change", String.valueOf(i) + ":" + String.valueOf(cos1)
                        + "," + String.valueOf(sin1));
                items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(lat3, lon3), String
                        .valueOf(i), "snippet"));
            }
```

If you want to insert overlays circling around an object at center, this is how you do it i guess...